# getting dimensions of images scaled in percentage by css

Tags: jquery, css, image-size

I'm trying to get the dimensions (width) of image elements which are scaled using percentage values by css.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
                    <ul id="gallery_content">
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/5.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/6.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/7.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/8.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/9.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/5.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/6.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/7.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/8.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/9.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and here the css:

```
ul#gallery_content li{ background:#FFF; list-style:none; display:inline; float:left; margin:0; height: 100%;}
ul#gallery_content li img { width:auto; height:100%; width:auto; }
```

I'm trying to get the actual width of the wrapper-Element (total of all image-widths).
When accessing them in a

```
$(document).ready(
    galItems = $('#gallery_content').children().children();
    galSize = 0;
    $.each(galItems, function(index, item){
        galSize += parseInt(item.width)
    });     
)
```

It gets all the image elements but does not get the calculated width.
Is there any chance to get the actual rendered width of the images with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried .width() as a function?

http://api.jquery.com/width/

```
galSize += parseInt(item.width());
```

**Edit after the question was solved:**

Turns out the problem actually was that the javascript was executed before the the page and the images was fully loaded.

This was solved by changing $(document).ready() to $(window).load().

Comment: Then i get a "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'width' of object #<HTMLImageElement> is not a function" Error

Comment: I guess that's because item isn't a jQuery object? Try getting $(this).width().

Comment: then i get 0 as width of the images.

Comment: Why don't try something like this then? $('#gallery_content').find('img').each(function() { galSize  += $(this).width()});

Comment: tI just encountered, that the js-code in the $(document).ready() call is executed before the site is rendered completely.
Might the problem be, that the width of the images is set to auto in the css and so is not accessible via js?

Comment: If that is the case you should probably use $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready().

Answer (score 0):

On the `ready()` event you should pass a function, so wrap you code within a function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var galItems = $('#gallery_content').children().children();
    var galSize = 0;
    $.each(galItems, function(index, item){
        galSize += +(item.width)
    });
});
```

Use the `+` symbol instead of `parseInt` to convert strings to number, it's faster.